# При нажатии на один из прикрепленных к методу pictureBox нарисовать в нем

Tags: c#, winforms

делаю крестики нолики 3 на 3 которые должны быть реализованы на pictureBox.хочу все 9 боксов присоединить к одному методу который будет определять, что сейчас рисовать и рисовать в боксе нужный рисунок. Вот пример как я сделал это только используя текст и кнопки

`
**

```
int whosemove=0;
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
            if (score%2==0)
            {
                whosemove++;
                sender.GetType().GetProperty("Text").SetValue(sender, "x");
            }
            else
            {
                whosemove++;
                sender.GetType().GetProperty("Text").SetValue(sender, "x");
            }
        }
```

**
`

Comment: Молодец! *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: А где вопрос? *(2 символа нужно)*